# My Json/javascript carousel is a no show, wont even display. Same with card-deck

Tags: json, ajax

So I'm a student in graphic design and i'm having some trubbel with getting my carousel and my card-deck to appear. The first block of code is the carousel, the second is the js in where i tried to make a card-deck. No errors in console when I check. Mind that this is a training excersice for me, and therefore it's a bit of a blend between pure javaScript and jQuery in some parts.

//carousel//

```
function loadCarouselEvent() {

    $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=world+war+two"), function(jsonResult) {
        let myItems = jsonResult.item;
        let liIndicators = document.getElementsByClassName(".carousel-indicators");
        let slideshowDiv = document.getElementsByClassName(".carousel-inner");

    $.each (myItems, function($index, $bookElement) {

        
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        if ($index == 0) {
            li.addClass("active")
        }
        li.attr ({
            "data-target":"#bookSlide",
            "data-to-slide":$index
        });

        liIndicators.append(li);

        
        let divItem = document.createElement("div");
        if ($index == 0) {
            divItem.addClass("carousel-item active");
        }else {
            divItem.addClass("carousel-item");
        }
    
        let bookImg = document.createElement("img");
        img.attr ({
            "src": myItems.volumeinfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
            "alt": myItems.volumeinfo.title,
            "class": ("bookImg d-block img-fluid"),
        });

        
        let bookText = document.createElement("div");
        bookText.addClass = ("carousel-caption d-none d-md-block");
        
        let caption = document.createElement("h3");
        caption.text = myItems.volumeinfo.title

        let author = document.createElement("p");
        author.text = myItems.volumeinfo.authors

        let bookCat = document.createElement("p");
        bookCat.text = myItems.volumeinfo.categories;

        let previewLink = document.createElement("a")
        previewLink = myItems.volumeinfo.previewLink;

        let buyLink = document.createElement("a");
        buyLink = myItems.volumeinfo.saleinfo.buyLink;


        bookText.append(caption);
        bookText.append(author);
        bookText.append(bookCat);
        bookText.append(previewLink);
        bookText.append(buyLink);
        divItem.append(bookImg);
        divItem.append(bookText);
        slideshowDiv.append(divItem);

        }) 
    } 
} 

window.onload = function() {
    loadCarouselEvent();
}


function loadJson() {
    
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open ("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=war+history+new+releases", true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.onreadystatechange === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhttp.status === 200) {
            let jsondata = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            presentBookCards(jsondata);
        } 
    } 
}
```

// card-deck //

```
function presentBookCards(jsondata) {
  row = document.querySelector("#newReleases");
  row.innerHTML = ””;

  jsondata.items.forEach(function (bookItem) {

    let colCard = document.createElement(”div”);
    colCard.setAttribute(”class”, ”col-md-4 pb-1 pb-md-0”)

    let cardCont = document.createElement(””div);
    cardCont.setAttribute(”class”, ”card”);

    let cardImg = document.createElement(”img”);
    cardImg.setAttribute(”src”, bookItem.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail);
    cardImg.setAttribute(”class”, ”card-img-top”);
    cardImg.setAttribute(”alt”, ”book thumbnail image”);
    cardCont.appendChild(img):

    let cardBody = document.createElement(”div”);
    cardBody.setAttribute(”class”, ”card-body”);

    let bookTitle = document.createElement(”h4”)
    bookTitle.setAttribute(”class”, ”card-title”);
    let t = document.createTextNode(item.volumeInfo.title);
    bookTitle.appendChild(t);

    let bookAuthor = document.createElement(”h6”)
    bookAuthor.setAttribute(”class”, ”card-title”);
    let a = document.createTextNode(bookItem.volumeInfo.authors);
    bookAuthor.appendChild(a);
    cardBody.appendChild(bookTitle);
    cardBody.appendChild(bookAuthor);

    let cardDescr = document.createElement(”p”);
    cardDescr.setAttribute(”class”, ”card-text”);
    let p = document.createTextNode(bookItem.volumeInfo.description);
    cardDescr.appendChild(p);
    cardBody.appendChild(cardDescr);  

    let btnFoot = document.createElement(”div”);
    btnFoot.setAttribute(”class”,”card-footer”);

    let readMore = document.createElement(”a”);
    readMore.setAttribute(”class”, ”card-link”);
    readMore.setAttribute(”href”,bookItem.saleInfo.previewLink);
    let btnText = document.createTextNode(”Read More”);
    readMore.appendChild(btnText);

    let buyBtn = document.createElement(”a”);
    buyBtn.setAttribute(”class”, ”card-link fa fa-shopping-cart”);
    buyBtn.setAttribute(”href”,bookItem.saleInfo.buyLink);

    btnFoot.appendChild(readMore);
    btnFoot.appendChild(buyBtn);
    cardCont.appendChild(btnFooter);
      
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Can you recreate your code under JS fiddle or any other code runner - https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Tried jsfiddle, excanged all the " " to ' ', for some reason jsfiddle did not like the dubble-quotes. After that, ran html and javascript... unfortunaly no error-reports what so ever.